# Layout in Apple Watch

Tags: iphone, watchkit, ios8-extension

I am making a calculator for Apple Watch I have inserted a group and inside that I have added 4 button but I can't find any option that those 4 buttons should adjust on both Apple Watch screen.

Apple Watch 38mm

[image: Screenshot]

Apple Watch 42mm

[image: Screenshot]

Group Properties

[image: Screenshot]

Button Properties

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use one `WKInterfaceGroup` per row and in the size inspector set "Relative to Container" width to 1 and height to 0.18.

[image]

Inside each group layout your `WKInterfaceButtons` setting Relative to Container heights to 1 and width 0.25 (4 elements per row).

[image]

Final result on 38mm:

[image]

and 42mm:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who might be trying to do similar things on Apple Watch kit, there is a very good basic calculator tutorial here:
http://www.noodlewerk.com/blog/calculator-apple-watch-tutorial/ 
(not my own tutorial, but something I came across in my own experimentation with the Kit)

Excerpt from article:

"Select both buttons and open the Attributes Inspector in the sidebar on the right. Keep the width option at ‘Relative to Container’ but change the value from 1 to 0.25."

This percentage setting allows UI elements to re-size relative to the display area, which is useful in situation like the Apple Watch where there are two discreet screen sizes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to let me know. Sorry, total beginner here. Still learning the ropes :)